# Comparing same index in 2 lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

I don't have a code for this because I have no idea how to do it, and couldn't find much help on Google.

Is there a way to find if the same indexes on 2 lists are the same?

For example:

```
x_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y_list = [1, 2, A, B, 5]
```

I want to know whether the first index of X is the same as the first index of Y, the second index of X is the same as the second index of Y, etc. I could do it like:

```
x_list[0] == y_list[0]
```

But need an infinite solution.

Comment: Why don't compare 2 lists directly, `x_list == y_list`

Comment: Do you mean that we need to check if **every** index corresponds to the same item in both list?

Comment: `any(x_list[i]==y_list[i] for i in range(min(len(x_list),len(y_list))))` This checks if **any** index corresponds to the same item in both list.

Comment: `len(x_list)==len(y_list) and all(x_list[i]==y_list[i] for i in range(len(x_list))` This checks if **every** index corresponds to the same item in both list.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) the lists and return the test (which returns a boolean as outcome):

```
[i == j for i, j in zip(x_list, y_list)]
```

You could use `any` to quickly check for the existence of a `False` (means the items are not the same) if you don't need the values:

```
any(i != j for i, j in zip(x_list, y_list))
```

The `any` version would break once a `False` is found meaning you may not have to traverse the whole lists except in the worst case.

Comment: Keep note that `izip` from [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) can be used in place of `zip`, and would be tremendously be more helpful when using `any()` to conserve memory.

Answer (score 4):

You can always use list comprehensions:

`[True if i == j else False for i,j in zip(x_list, y_list)]`.
You can also check less explicit answer by Moses Koledoye, where `True if i == j else False` is juzt `i == j`

zip function will combine your lists like [(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 'A'), (4, 'B'), (5, 5)]

Result: `[True, True, False, False, True]`

Also suggest to use izip from itertools if you use Python2.

Comment: `True if i == j else False` is really just `i == j`... Why the extra codes?

Comment: ```True if i == j ``` is not idiomatic Python.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
   [i == j for i, j in zip(x_list, y_list)]
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer OP's question when comparing items from the same index of multiple lists.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with below definition if you would like to compare lists with different size. This would fetch either unique index elements or not rather than a list of True or False.

```
def is_uniq_lists(x_list, y_list):
    if len(x_list) != len(y_list):
        return False

    for (i,j) in zip(x_list, y_list): 
        if i != j: return False 

    return True
```

Result:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]    # Unique lists
>>> b = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> List.is_uniq_lists(a,b)
True
>>> a=[1,2,3,4,5]    # Different lists
>>> b=[1,2,'A','B',5]
>>> List.is_uniq_lists(a,b)
False
>>> a=[1,2,3,4,5]
>>> b=[1,2,3,4,5,6]    # Lists of unequal length
>>> List.is_uniq_lists(a,b)
False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def compareArrayIndex(L1, L2):
    if(len(L1) == len(L2)):
        for i in range(0, len(L2)):
            if(L1[i] > L2[i]):
                # logic
            elif(L1[i] < L2[i]):
                # logic
            else:
                # logic
        return value
```