# How to check if any element in iterable1 is present in the iterable2 at the same index in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

for example have a look at the following snippet

```
iter1 = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]

iter2 = [6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22]
```

as multiple items are present in both list but not at the same index so this should return None or False basically no result

now have a look at this case

```
iter1 = [3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21]

iter2 = [6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
```

In the case above we have 12 in both the lists at same index and for this I need the result to be True i.e strictly based on the index

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparing same index in 2 lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38035317/comparing-same-index-in-2-lists)

Comment: `any(iter1[i] == iter2[i] for i in range(len(iter1)))` assuming they are the same length

Comment: Use `zip(iter1, iter2)` and check if the pairs contain equal values.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the size of both your lists are same, try this:

```
for i in range(0, len(iter1)):
    if iter1[i] == iter2[i]:
        print("True")
```